# How to solve draw gradient below line - PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/104?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

[github link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/104)

I would like a gradient and, if possible, choose components colors and orientation.

is this issues solved?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i found it's answer

```
LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1");
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
```

fade_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#00ffffff"
    android:endColor="#6a64c7ff" />
</shape>
```

but fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above

```
if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
   // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
   Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
   set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
} else {
      set1.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

reference [MPAndroidChart - link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java)

Comment: I have to add `setDrawFilled(true)` to make the gradient available. Thanks for the code snippet!

Comment: Is it possible to make the line above the fill, also gradient?